# How Can I call id on one page to other page

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, sql

I have a table I am pulling data from MySQL. Clicking the update button next to this table, a new popup appears and the form will be entered with the data. But I want to call the data automatically into forms thanks to the id in the row in the table. How can I fetch this id?

```
  <tr>
    <td> <?php echo $row['id']; ?> </td>
    <td> <?php echo $row['username']; ?> </td>
    <td> <?php echo $row['password']; ?> </td>
    <td> <?php echo $row['number']; ?> </td>
    <td> <?php echo $row['tarihilk']; ?> </td>
    <td> <?php echo $row['tarihson']; ?> </td>
    <td><a href="edit.php?id=$res[id]"> <i class=" fa fa-edit" style="font-size:24px"></i></a></td>
  </tr>
```

Also, there is edit.php file.

```
    <?php
include("config.php");
$id = $_GET['id'];
$result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * from users WHERE id=$id");
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    $username = $row['username'];
    $password = $row['password'];
    $number   = $row['number'];
    $tarihilk = $row['tarihilk'];
    $tarihson = $row['tarihson'];
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to echo the variable:

```
<a href="edit.php?id=<?= $res['id'] ?>"> ... </a>
```

The `<?= $var ?>` syntax is just a shorter way of writing: `<?php echo $var ?>`. I also added quotes around the key (just like you've done when echoing it further up in the table).

Other than that, the code looks correct.

***Note:*** You are also wide open for [SQL injection](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/SQL_Injection) attacks and should use parameterized [prepared statements](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) when using user data in your queries. Never trust any data that comes from the user. In your case, this: `$id = (int)$_GET['id'];` (casting the value as an integer) should be safe enough, but it's good to get used to prepared statements.

Comment: thanks for your comment. Now I get an error in popup  "mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, bool given in C:\wamp64\www\edit.php on line 5"

It points the while loop in the edit.php

Comment: Nice. If this helped you, feel free to accept the answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript to pass the values you are getting from the database into the individual fields.

Comment: There is a row when I click the update button, a new popup opens. Then I want to fetch values from the database but my pointer is an id. That's why I'm trying to call id on the other page. How can I use script with this?

Comment: In your code i can see youve already passed the values from the database to the php variables youve created. What you have to do next is to pass the values through the edit button with javascript